# HQL request in JSP

Tags: jsp, hql

I try to execute an HQL request in my JSP, the request refers to a many to many relation between Projet and Acteur. But i'm getting these errors:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/GestionDeProjet] threw exception [org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Projet of: bean.Acteur [from bean.Acteur a join a.Projet p where p.libelle= :libelle]] with root cause
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Projet of: bean.Acteur
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1978)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:367)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:500)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:655)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3903)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3689)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3567)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:564)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
    at
```

Here is my JSP:

```
<%  String jo=request.getParameter("valeur"); 
 System.out.println(jo);
 %>
    <% Session session1=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session1.beginTransaction();
    Query qry =  session1.createQuery("from Acteur a join a.Projet p where p.libelle= :libelle");
    qry.setString("libelle",jo);

    List list = qry.list();
    Iterator <Object[]>iter=list.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){

        Object[] obj=iter.next();
        System.out.println(obj[0]+ " " + obj [1]);

    }
    %>
```

Acteur.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 25 avr. 2015 06:50:10 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="bean.Acteur" table="ACTEUR">
        <id name="idActeur" type="int">
            <column name="IDACTEUR" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="nomActeur" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NOMACTEUR" />
        </property>
        <property name="prenomActeur" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PRENOMACTEUR" />
        </property>
        <property name="mailActeur" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="MAILACTEUR" />
        </property>
        <property name="fonctionActeur" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="FONCTIONACTEUR" />
        </property>
        <property name="roleActeur" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="ROLEACTEUR" />
        </property>
        <set name="acteurProjets" table="PROJET_ACTEUR" inverse="true"
            lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="IDACTEUR" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many class="bean.Projet">
                <column name="ID" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Projet.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 25 avr. 2015 06:50:10 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="bean.Projet" table="PROJET">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="libelle" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="LIBELLE" />
        </property>
        <property name="site" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="SITE" />
        </property>
        <property name="finalite" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="FINALITE" />
        </property>
        <property name="date_actuelle" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DATE_ACTUELLE" />
        </property>
        <property name="date_debut" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DATE_DEBUT" />
        </property>
        <property name="date_previsionnelle" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DATE_PREVISIONNELLE" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="domaine" class="bean.Domaine" fetch="join">
            <column name="IDDOMAINE" />
        </many-to-one>
        <set name="assignedActeurs" table="PROJET_ACTEUR" inverse="false"
            lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many class="bean.Acteur">
                <column name="IDACTEUR" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
        <set name="assignedBénéficiaires" table="PROJET_BENEFICIAIRE"
            inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many class="bean.Bénéficiaire">
                <column name="IDBENEFICIAIRE" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>

        <many-to-one name="chefprojet" class="bean.Chefprojet"
            fetch="join">
            <column name="ID_CHEF" />
        </many-to-one>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I didn't want to place the code Java and the request HQL in the JSP, but in fact i had to pass a variable to this JSP and i couldn't get it in the Servlet, which is "jo",so when i get it in the JSP i place all of my code there.

Comment: May we see your entity code as well?

Comment: show your hibernate entity.

Comment: Of course i'll edit my post

Comment: I'm not very familiar with xml tags in hibernate, and would like to see java entity. What I think is you must use a.acterProjects instead of a.project

Comment: Ah Ok! I try this i'm not getting any error, but instead of displaying the result, it get displayed: bean.Acteur@5b96c221 bean.Projet@b48238f

Comment: It's Ok now, i just had to specify the columns in the Query. Thanks @Prasad Kharkar for your response !

Comment: @salma that is because you have not overridden `toString()` method in entity class. Ideally you should extract properties from Project entity, but if you want to simply print the object itself, you need to learn significance of toString method in java. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()